# python manage.py runserver not recognized

Tags: django

I am new to python and django i am creating first tutorial app.

I created app file using following command:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

After that successfully created a file in directory

But how to run python manage.py runserver i am getting error `not recognized as an internal or extrnal command`

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

But how to run `python manage.py runserver` i am getting error `not recognized as an internal or extrnal command`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `cd` into mysite from there.

Use `cd mysite` from the command line. Then run `python manage.py runserver` and the dev server will startup in the current (or a new if there inst a current) browser window.

To visualize this for you:

```
current_dir/ <-- your here now
        mysite/      < -- use cd mysite to get to here!
             manage.py  <-- and use this
             mysite/   
                    __init__.py
                    urs.py
                    settings.py
                    ect.
```

current_dir is where you initially created the project.

**Pro tip**: you always have to come back to this exact dir to use manage.py, so if you get that error again while your making the polls app; you are probably just in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the directory that the app you created resides in then run the command `manage.py runserver` on windows or `python manage.py runserver` in a Unix Terminal.

It is typical to create a separate directory for your Django projects.  A typical directory would be:

```
C:\DjangoProjects\
```

You would then put the location of `django-admin.py` on your `PYTHONPATH` in your command shell and run the startproject command and the new project would be created in the current directory that you are in.  If you have already created the project, you could also just cut and paste it to a different directory that way your Django projects are not in the same directory as your Python / Django source code.

Either way, in the end go the directory for the app you created, so:

```
C:\DjangoProjects\mysite\
```

and from that directory run the `manage.py runserver` command and this will start the `app` running on your local machine.